# How to use AJAX to download files without page referesh in Octobercms?

Tags: php, ajax, octobercms

I am new to laravel and october cms. I want to add a button to allow users download a PDF file, 'a.pdf', without directing to a new page. I know that I have to use AJAX and send a download http response in order to make browsers show a 'Save As...' dialog box. So far this is what I have accomplished:

```
title = "Sandbox"
url = "/test"
layout = "default"
==
<?php
function onDownload()
{
    $pathToFile = Url::to("/storage/app/media/a.pdf");
    $fileName = "download.pdf";
    $headers = [
        'HTTP/1.1 200 OK',
        'Pragma: public',
        'Content-Type: application/pdf'
    ];
    return Response::download($pathToFile, $fileName, $headers);
}
?>
==
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline" data-request="onDownload">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-attach-loading>Download</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I get "The file "http://localhost/october/storage/app/media/a.pdf" does not exist" error using above code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hope you have createad the folder location and put the file into that path `october/storage/app/media/a.pdf` an?

Comment: Yes of course I've done that!

Comment: can you share absolute path of the file location?

Comment: The path to the file is "http://localhost/october/storage/app/media/a.pdf".

Comment: I can download the file by typing the above URl in browser.

Comment: thanks, this make sense

Answer (score 0):

Please change the header into associative array,

```
$headers = array(
                 'Content-Type'=>'application/pdf',
           );
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I tried your solution but still get the same result. The complete error is:

Comment: "The file "http://localhost/october/storage/app/media/a.pdf" does not exist" on line 37 of E:\xampp\htdocs\october\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\File\File.php

Comment: can you share complete file location like `/var/www/html/project/location/file.pdf`

Comment: i'm currently developing on windows using XAMPP. My file is stored at E:\xampp\htdocs\october\storage\app\media\a.pdf where XAMPP's root runs from E:\xampp\htdocs\

Answer (score 0):

For any who may find this useful (**This works for files uploaded via media manager**). Got this working by adding the AJAX handler in my layout code php section.

```
function onDownloadButtonClicked(){

    $pathToFile = base_path('storage/app/media/path/actual filename here');
    $fileName = "filename shown on download here";
    $headers = [
        'HTTP/1.1 200 OK',
        'Pragma: public',
        'Content-Type: application/pdf'
    ];
    return Response::download($pathToFile, $fileName, $headers);
}
```

Added this on the pages and partials

```
{{ form_open({ request: 'onDownloadButtonClicked' }) }}
<button type="submit" class="tg-btn tg-btnicon" data-attach-loading>
    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Download Here
</button>
{{ form_close() }}
```

**Update**: For file uploaded via the backend using a plugin Octobercms generates dynamic links. To download the files just create a frontend component. Follow easy tutorial [Watch + learn](https://watch-learn.com/making-websites-with-october-cms/making-websites-with-october-cms-part-09-images-and-galleries) to create a simple plugin model for backend uploading and [Mastering components](https://octobercms.com/blog/post/mastering-components) for a barebones frontend download component. Once the file details are acquired a simple href will do for file download.

```
<a href="{{ post.attachment.path }}"
            download="{{ post.attachment.file_name }}"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> &nbsp Download File</a>
```

The names posts and attachment could be anything depending plugin model form design.